# How to set text on LineString in Mapbox SDK?

Tags: java, android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am working with the LineLayer from Mapbox SDK and having problems with getting text to show up on the line. There is an [example](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/maps/examples/create-a-line-layer/) from Mapbox.

This is what I have so far:

```
// Create a list to store our line coordinates.
routeCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();
routeCoordinates.add(Point.fromLngLat(-95.9928, 36.1540));
routeCoordinates.add(Point.fromLngLat(-95.9870, 36.1397));

// Create the LineString from the list of coordinates and then make a GeoJSON
// FeatureCollection so we can add the line to our map as a layer.
LineString lineString = LineString.fromLngLats(routeCoordinates);
FeatureCollection featureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(new com.mapbox.geojson.Feature[] {com.mapbox.geojson.Feature.fromGeometry(lineString)});
Source geoJsonSource = new GeoJsonSource("line-source", featureCollection);
mapbox.addSource(geoJsonSource);

LineLayer lineLayer = new LineLayer("linelayer", "line-source");
// The layer properties for our line. This is where we make the line dotted, set the
// color, etc.
lineLayer.setProperties(
     PropertyFactory.lineCap(Property.LINE_CAP_ROUND),
     PropertyFactory.lineJoin(Property.LINE_JOIN_ROUND),
     PropertyFactory.lineWidth(5f),
     PropertyFactory.lineColor(Color.parseColor("#e55e5e")),
     PropertyFactory.textField("some text"),
     PropertyFactory.textColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
);
mapbox.addLayer(lineLayer);
```

It won't add the string to the line as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [LineLayer class](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.0.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/layers/LineLayer.html) is based on the line layer in Mapbox GL JS. You can see available properties of this type of layer [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layers-line), in the style spec documentation. As you can see, textField and textColor are not available properties.

One way to accomplish this would be to create an additional layer - this time of type **SymbolLayer** (https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.0.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/layers/SymbolLayer.html). This layer would have the same line data from your GeoJsonSource. You can read more about symbol layers [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layers-symbol), but you can set text for this layer, and then set the [symbol-placement](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layout-symbol-symbol-placement) property to **line** or **line-center** so the text aligns properly.